# PHP not getting response from python?

Tags: php, python

Php never get response If calling an API in python and it takes more than 5 minutes. so I was checking with time.sleep(300) in python, but it works.

I do not know why php not getting response from python while calling an API.

**CODE**

**test.php**

```
<?php
  $file_id=1; 
  $response=exec('python /home/xyz/test.py '.$file_id);

  echo $response;

 ?>
```

**test.py**

```
import os, json
import sys


sleep(300)
#sleep(420)
print "hello"
```

Comment: Perhaps your PHP server is timing out after 3 minutes...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe python is throwing an error and not printing to stdout because of that error.
Did you forget to import sleep from the time module, or where does it come from?

It should be:

```
import time
time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention in my question **import time time.sleep** . I was testing with sample code, It is working but actually my python program calling an api and it takes more than 5 minutes and php never get response.